# I am trying to print prices from a particular column from my sqlite database and it gives me a Tuple index out of range Error

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

i have a table in my database, and i am trying to extract all items from a particular column and store each item in variables, but i get a Tuple Index out of Range Error please help, i also try this method to get rows and store them into variables but i dont know why it does not work for column.

```
c.execute("SELECT Selling_Price FROM stock_records")
            result = c.fetchone()
            for i in result:
                r1 = i[0]
                r2 = i[1]
                r3 = i[2]
                r4 = i[3]
                r5 = i[4]
```

Comment: You realize you're selecting one column, right?

Comment: yes i do but i was testing that to see if it would work, even when i use the fetchall() method it doesn't work.

Comment: Let me try again: You're selecting one row with `fetchone()` and that row contains just a single value. `result[0]` has that value.  What I assume you want to do is call `fetchone` until there are no more rows returned (`None` is returned).  You need to rethink your loop.

Comment: Think in these terms: `while True:
  row = c.fetchone()
  if row is None: break
  print(row)
`

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT Selling_Price FROM stock_records`

Will extract **only** the **Selling_Price** column for each row, as such only the one element/index **`i[0]`** will be available (in range) **`i[1]`** will be out of range.

If you used `SELECT Selling_Price, another_column FROM stock_records` (assuming that another_column is a column in the table). Then two values per row would exists and you could then access both **`i[0]`** and **`i[1]`** but not **`i[2]`** and so on.

You probably want to use `SELECT * FROM stock_records`, in which case each row will have a value for all columns in the table and thus **`i[0]`** through to **`i[4]`** will work (assuming there are 5 columns in the table).